# How to plot this FourierTransform?

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, integral-transforms

I need to find the Fourier transform and plot the function: Delta(x-xo)
I've already tried to write it as: `FourierTransform [DiracDelta[x - Subscript[x, 0]], x, w]` but it isn't working.

Comment: Don't use `Subscript`: it's pretty, but it may cause sneaky problems. Just use `x0` instead: `FourierTransform[DiracDelta[x - x0], x, w]` returns `E^(I*w*x0)/Sqrt[2*Pi]`.

Comment: Fourier transforms live on the complexes. For example, putting `x0=1`, you may look at `ComplexPlot3D[E^(I*w)/Sqrt[2*Pi], {w, -5 - 5*I, 5 + 5*I}, 
 PlotRange -> All]`.